# Why would AppleIDAuthAgent take nearly 100% CPU?

Tags: apple-id, launchd, activity-monitor, macos, authentication

The AppleIDAuthAgent process on my 2007 Mac Pro running OS X 10.7.5 is taking up 95-100 % CPU continuously.

I use it whenever I go to work.

I also use it as a server. I occasionally pull/push using `git` and to access it via SSH and remote desktop from home or elsewhere. It's behind a major university firewall and has fairly high security settings.

More info:

- Parent Process is `launchd`.
- The process has no recent hangs.
- Real Memory Size: 122.3 MB
- Virtual Memory Size: 18.49 GB  <-- Suspicious....
- Shared Memory Size: 4.2 MB
- Private Memory Size: 66.0 MB
- Virtual Private Memory: 291.1 MB
- CPU time: 573 hrs

I can provide other info if requested.

Comment: Try sampling the process to see what it's doing.  You can do it from Activity Monitor (sorry, I'm not sure about the exact command for 10.7.5).

Comment: Also, have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: I did restart the machine. Things went down (CPU around 10-20%), but were very, very slowly increasing.

Comment: Then it's very likely that it's simply a software bug within AppleIDAuthAgent process, triggered by something in your Mac's configuration.   If you can get in, I strongly recommend filing a report at [bugreport.apple.com](bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I simply killed that bugger and things went on normally.

Comment: @Bob: Apple no longer will let my computer update because my hardware is too old. Is it worth submitting a bug report even so?